# NSGA-II ( Non- Dominating Sorting Algorithm )

Tags: algorithm, sorting, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I have studied  about Non dominating sorting algorithtm (nsga-II).

Algorithm is given on this link .
            http://church.cs.virginia.edu/genprog/images/2/2f/Nsga_ii.pdf

I want to know it's real life application    with examples.....I  tried to search on the internet ,but no where found it.

If you have any ideas or relevent data/link  ,please share with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find some real-life applications by just searching : "NSGA-II + applications" in Google Scholar : http://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=10&q=nsga-ii+application&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5

The ones who proposed NSGA-II are, indeed, Prof. Kalyanmoy Deb and his co-authors Samir Agrawal, Amrit Pratap and T. Meyarivan.

In my own research, I surveyed a number of NSGA-II based approaches for the portfolio optimization problem (a financial engineering problem), you can find a paper at the link :  https://editorialexpress.com/cgi-bin/conference/download.cgi?db_name=CEF2012&paper_id=167

Answer (score 4):

In my own, personal experience, I've used NSGA-II for two problems.
The Multi Objective Travelling salesman problem and
Community Detection in Networks.
These were mainly academic studies, so they can't be called real life applications.

For more concrete examples of NSGA-II in action, I know that, NSGA-II is used in optimization of chemical processes. Prof. S.K. Gupta, from whom I learnt about NSGA-II, did so himself and you can check out some of the practical applications in his list of papers
http://www.iitk.ac.in/che/Publ%20List%20SKG%20June%202012.pdf particularly paper #160, 163, 164, 177 and 187.

I'm not sure, but the inventor himself, Prof. Kalyanmoy Deb , also uses it in the field of Mechanical Engineering.

Basically, you can use it, in any Industrial Process, where optimization is required, be it a chemical process, or the design of car parts.

Answer (score 1):

I used NSGA-II in a multi-objective evolutionary approach to optimize an artificial neural network that corresponds to a computational model of a part of the brain which is supposed to be a low-level system for action selection. If you are interested you may find more information on http://francky.me/publications.php#mRF2011

Note that any other Pareto-compliant ranking method would have probably worked.